# Fancybox2 opening in top left corner in IE9 and older

Tags: internet-explorer, doctype, fancybox-2

(This is my first post so my apologies if I've missed something)

I've searched and found some information regarding Fancybox2 requiring a valid doctype to work in Internet Explorer.

However, when I use the following doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
```

The fancybox window opens in the top left corner of the screen and does not update the size of the lightbox based on the values entered.

When I use an alternative doctype, such as:

```
<!doctype html>
```

It works perfectly in all browsers.

Unfortunately, updating the doctype for all the sites I need to take care of and negating any design impacts would be quite time consuming. As such, I figured I would ask:

**Has anyone had any success with Fancybox2 and the Transitional doctype listed above with IE9 and older? Any advice on how to overcome?**

Thank you for any assistance :)

Comment: I think 4.0 is deprecated and IE9 for sure is switching to quirks mode. I think you should be using 4.01 instead like `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` ... check http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html for the current recommended doctypes

Comment: Thank you for the note - you're quite right - however, updating the doctype in my situation isn't really an option. Thank you though. :)